# Can you rate limit an Azure Function or output of a Storage Queue?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

I have a Storage Queue triggered Python Azure Function that submits a job to a third-party rate-limited API (1 request/minute). The queue that triggers the function will periodically receive a burst of messages, so I need a way to ensure that the function will be triggered immediately upon receiving the first message, 1 minute later on the second message, 2 minutes later on the third message, etc. until the queue is empty.

Is it possible to either rate-limit the queue or the function so I am only running the function once a minute until the queue is empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to rate-limit a storage queue (other than the queue naturally being rate-limited by the storage transaction rate limits, which are several orders of magnitude greater than your currently-desired rate-limit).

Rather than trigger your Azure function off of queue message arrival, you can set up a timer trigger for your Azure function. This will allow you to set up, say, a 1-minute interval on the timer, where your function can read a message and call the 3rd-party API.

You'll need to specify a timer value, which is an NCRONTAB expression, with the following format:

`{second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day-of-week}`

An every-1-minute expression will look like:

`"0 */1 * * * *"`

More info on timer triggers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer).

Comment: Thanks! It would be great if there was a way for the function to only run if there are messages in the queue, especially as we only expect it to run around a dozen times a day, so the remaining 1400+ runs will be doing nothing. This seems like it is probably the most reliable solution given Azure's capabilities, though a little overkill at the same time.

Comment: There are definitely ways to optimize. But keep in mind: even checking a queue once-per-minute, every day, your monthly storage transaction cost will be like... a few pennies. Likewise, your Function usage seems to fall below the threshold of Free tier, so the cost of such a setup is minimal.

Comment: @wkeithvan Actually, queue polling can be limited. You can learn about the maxPollingInterval. This can allow your Function to lower the frequency of queue checks, if there is no messages in the queue. The frequency will be lower until your queue has message again. I may not describe it clearly, you can look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#trigger---polling-algorithm

Comment: @BowmanZhu That defines the max interval, not the min interval. I need a minimum of 1 minute, this won't work. Additionally, that is only configurable in the `host.json`, so it would affect all my other queue triggered functions.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the **NextVisibleTime** property:

[CloudQueueMessage.NextVisibleTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.queue.cloudqueuemessage.nextvisibletime?view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: Interesting approach. Unfortunately I don't think setting visibility time will solve this. If a message burst arrives, there would need to be a writer handling all incoming messages, explicitly pushing each msg on the queue in carefully-calculated increasing visibility time. If this handler runs in more than one instance, visibility time will be extremely difficult to properly coordinate. If that code restarts, it has to track previous state. If even one message fails to be properly consumed from the queue, it then reappears for later processing (and no way to guarantee when it reappears).

Comment: The burst of messages was where our problem was going to be as multiple parallel executions would all collide without some coordination. Using Storage Tables to look up how much to add in the visibility wasn't great as there were no locks. I looked into using the [singleton functionality](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json) with the queue `batch_size=1`, but that required a separate app as the `host.json` settings are global across the app. Unfortunately, that wasn't very stable and felt incredibly hacky, so I think the TimerTrigger will have to do.