# Azure Queue Trigger - Dequeue rate limit

Tags: azure, azure-functions, message-queue, azure-queues, queuetrigger

I have a Azure queue trigger app. It tries to process message asap but when I have 1000s of message in the queue I want to limit number queue messages it process per second. Is there a way to setup limit?

My goal is to slow down the rate at which my function processes messages.

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.24",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "queueName": "fred",
      "connection": "",
      "name": "myQueueItem"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../bin/run.dll",
  "entryPoint": "Fred.Run"
}
```

Comment: you can do that using Event Hub and Throughput Unit. I don't think there's a way to do that using Queue Trigger.

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58651099/272109) to a very similar question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot limit to "X requests per second" as this depends on your processing logic. However, you can [configure the batch size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json-v1#queues) and then also to how many instances your Function will scale out.

See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=csharp#concurrency

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_max_dynamic_application_scale_out